# Arrow function this behaviour

Tags: javascript, typescript, this, arrow-functions

Example 1

```
const obj = {
  perimeter: () => {
    console.log(this); // this points to window
  }
}
```

obj.perimeter()

```
const obj = {
    sing(){
    console.log(this);
    const b = () =>{
        console.log(this); // this points to obj
    }
    b();
  }
}
```

obj.sing()

Arrow function this points lexical scope why the first output is different?

Arrow function this points lexical scope why the first output is different?

Comment: in the second example, the lexical scope is the `sing` method, which has a `this` of `obj` when called (as you do) as `obj.sing()`. In the first example, the surrounding scope is the global scope, so that's why you get the global `window` object as `this`.

Answer (score -2):

because the arrow function as no `this` context.
[JavaScript Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions?retiredLocale=de#description)